# How to avoid changing the import name of the Library using NRWL move command?

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I am using the NRWL move command to move lib into the parent folder to achieve a well-organized project structure.

**for example the command:**
nx g @nrwl/angular:move --project graphql core/graphql

It moves lib into the parent folder but it changes the name of the library too as You can see on the following output of the angular.json file.

```
 "graphql": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/graphql",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/graphql/src",
```

**changes to:**

```
  "core-graphql": { // I dont want to change this name only the path to module
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/core/graphql",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/core/graphql/src",
```

I have to find all occurrences of the new library name and change them back after each move command.

Is possible to avoid this by some flag in command? I tried to use params that are mentioned in docs but without luck, the name is changed every time.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Project name and the project path stays in sync in nrwl workspace and hence it makes sense on why the project name is getting updated from `graphql` to `core-graphql`.

Also, the move command by default updates all occurrences of the import path of the moved project to the new location (https://nx.dev/packages/angular/generators/move#updateimportpath), so I don't think one would want the same project name even after moving it to a new location. You can avoid the import path update by setting `updateimportpath` to false while running the command but that would only cause more confusion in the workspace.